# verifying two session variable upon log in

Tags: php, session, authentication

I have to pages that requires login. admin.php and rehab.php. upon login i set two session variable:

```
if($row[2]=='Admin'){
    // Initializing Session
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['user']=$username; // Initializing Session user
    $_SESSION['dept']='Admin'; // Initializing Session dept.

    header('location: admin.php');
}
    else if($row[2]=='Rehabilitation Services'){
        $_SESSION['user']=$username; // Initializing Session
        $_SESSION['dept']='Rehabilitation Services';

   header('location: rehab.php');
}
```

This both pages have include header.php (where username can be seen). I've decided to put the session validation in header.php:

```
   session_start();
      if (!(isset($_SESSION['user']) && $_SESSION['user'] != '')) {
        header ("Location: login.php");
      }
```

so whenever someone will access admin page by typing in in the browser (../admin.php) or (../rehab.php) it will be re-directed to the login page.

My problem is, if a REHAB user is now logged on. (../rehab.php) whenever i try to change rehab.php to admin.php IT CAN STILL BE ACCESSED! i try putting this in the top of admin.php but it doesn't seem to work.

```
if ((isset($_SESSION['dept'])) && $_SESSION['dept']!='Admin'){
    session_destroy();
}
```

Comment: why don't you initialize session before first if?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the rehab.php page, if you want to restrict access only to those who are logged in and have a 'Rehabilitation Services' dept assigned, you should use:

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['user']) || 
   (isset($_SESSION['dept']) && $_SESSION['dept']!='Rehabilitation Services')){
       header ("Location: login.php");
 }
```

Comment: nice! i put this to every user page and remove the validation in the header page and it work just how i wanted it to. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

This should work; there are couple of things I've noticed and you're code structure is good as far as what you're trying to accomplish:

```
session_start(); // Have this as the first thing on the script 
                 // at the top before anything else above it 
if($row[2]=='Admin'){
    // Initializing Session
    session_start(); // Remove this; you need to put session_start 
                     // at the top of the script

    $_SESSION['user'] = $username; // Is the $username coming in 
                                   // from $_POST? Should this be 
                                   // $_POST['username'] unless you 
                                   // defined it beforehand 

    $_SESSION['dept'] = "Admin"; // Initializing Session dept. 
                                 // This is ok. 

    header('location: admin.php');

} elseif($row[2] == "Rehabilitation Services"){ //Keep this in one line
        $_SESSION['user'] = $username; // Initializing Session
        $_SESSION['dept'] = "Rehabilitation Services";

   header('location: rehab.php');
}

   session_start();
      if (!(isset($_SESSION['user']) && $_SESSION['user'] != '')) {
      if (!isset($_SESSION['user']) && $_SESSION['user'] != '') { 
      // corrected line above, you can also use empty() function  

        header ("Location: login.php");
      }


if ((isset($_SESSION['dept'])) && $_SESSION['dept']!='Admin'){
if (isset($_SESSION['dept']) && $_SESSION['dept'] != 'Admin'){
//Corrected line above
    session_destroy();
}
```